# Error running SQL command

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have some SQL code I'm executing in a console application. It's throwing:

> "system.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Incorrect syntax near the
>   keyword 'TB'.'

I've tried to change the code multiple times to get it to work properly, but it keeps throwing the same error. Through trying to fix it I've figured out that the last "TB" on the second to last row is responsible for the error, where it says ") TB". Does anyone have an idea why it doesn't like that TB there? Here is the code:

```
 string SQLCode = "SELECT TB.RowType,TB.company,TB.Account,TB.segvalue1,TB.segvalue2,TB.segvalue3,TB.segvalue4,TB.fiscalyear,TB.fiscalperiod,SUM(TB.BalanceAmt) as tbBalanceAmt" +
                    "FROM(SELECT 'Actual' AS RowType,GLJ.company,GLJ.glaccount AS Account,GLJ.segvalue1,GLJ.segvalue2,GLJ.segvalue3,GLJ.SegValue4," +
                    "GLJ.fiscalyear,GLJ.fiscalperiod,GLJ.jedate,GLJ.description,GLJ.vendornum,GLJ.apinvoicenum,SUM(GLJ.debitamount - GLJ.creditamount) as glBalanceAmt,"+
                    "GLJ.groupid,GLJ.posteddate FROM GLJrnDtl GLJ GROUP BY GLJ.company,GLJ.glaccount,GLJ.segvalue1,GLJ.segvalue2,GLJ.segvalue3,"+
                    "GLJ.SegValue4,GLJ.fiscalyear,GLJ.fiscalperiod,GLJ.jedate,GLJ.description,GLJ.vendornum,GLJ.apinvoicenum,GLJ.groupid,GLJ.posteddate"+ 
                    " UNION ALL SELECT 'Budget' AS RowType,GLB.company,GLB.BalanceAcct AS Account,GLB.segvalue1,GLB.segvalue2,GLB.segvalue3,GLB.segvalue4,GLB.fiscalyear,GLB.fiscalperiod,"+
                "GLB.Date01 AS jedate,'' AS description,'' AS vendornum,'' AS apinvoicenum,SUM(GLB.BudgetAmt) as gbBalanceAmt,'' AS groupid,"+
                    "0 AS posteddate FROM GLBudgetDtl GLB WHERE GLB.segvalue3 <> '' AND GLB.BalanceType = 'D'"+
                "GROUP BY GLB.company,GLB.BalanceAcct,GLB.segvalue1,GLB.segvalue2,GLB.segvalue3,GLB.segvalue4,GLB.fiscalyear,GLB.fiscalperiod,GLB.Date01, GLB.BudgetAmt) TB"+
                " WHERE tb.Company = NVV AND TB.fiscalyear = '2017' AND tb.fiscalperiod BETWEEN 1 AND 10 and tb.segvalue1 = '4450'";
```

Comment: Your code has multiple errors.  I would suggest you start with a very simple query and add components in one-by-one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have no spaces at the end of your strings. That means that

`tbBalanceAmt" + "FROM`

gets evaluated to `thBalanceAmtFrom`.

Comment: Someone care to explain their downvote?

Comment: While the answer itself is correct, you should not answer off-topic questions.  Typography issues, exactly like this one, are off-topic as per the help center.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto: I would hardly consider this a typography issue. The user isn't asking how to make the code more readable. Rather, they're trying to figure out what they did wrong.

Comment: This post is, indirectly, asking for debugging help. We are not here to teach them how to debug and see what their code is doing. If the OP had debugged, they would have seen the error upfront.